Show Item based on the pathName in NextJs Server Component
I have a layout in which I have two Detail Pages One is User and another is Company and In this two I need to highlight user or company based on the page they are in I have urls as below

/user/details
/company/details

Now I need to highlight the tab based on the page they are in
/user/details --> High Light the User Tab
/company/details -->High Light the company Tab
import { useTranslation } from '@/app/i18n'
import { fallbackLng, languages } from '@/app/i18n/settings'
import { headers } from 'next/headers'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { Trans } from 'react-i18next/TransWithoutContext'

const Layout = async ({
  children,
  params: { lng },
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
  params: {
    lng: string
  }
}) => {
  if (languages.indexOf(lng) < 0) lng = fallbackLng
  const { t } = await useTranslation(lng)
  let isUserTab = false

  if (headers().get('referer')?.includes('user')) {
    isUserTab = true
  }

  return (
    <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 w-screen h-screen z-1000">
      <div className=" flex  items-center justify-center w-full h-full bg-red-500 absolute z-1000 ">
        <div className=" flex  bg-[rgb(255,255,255)] items-center justify-center">
          <div className=" flex flex-col bg-[white] w-[500px] items-center justify-center">
            <Image
              src="/assets/Icons/test.svg"
              width={100}
              height={72}
              alt="test"
            />
            <p>
              <Trans t={t} i18nKey="Welcome">
                Welcome
              </Trans>
            </p>
            <p>
              <Trans t={t} i18nKey="Details">
                Details
              </Trans>
            </p>
            <div className=" flex flex-row gap-[10px] ">
              <Link href="/user/details">
                <p className={`${isUserTab ? 'bg-[green]' : ''} min-w-[100px]`}>
                  <Trans t={t} i18nKey="USER">
                    USER
                  </Trans>
                </p>
              </Link>
              <p className={`${!isUserTab ? 'bg-[green]' : ''} min-w-[100px]`}>
                <Link href="/company/details">
                  <Trans t={t} i18nKey="COMPANY">
                    COMPANY
                  </Trans>
                </Link>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div>{children}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout


I know how to do it in client side but Is there any way to achieve it by using ssr Am I missing something important any help is appreciated.
FYI:I'm using Nextjs App Router

Most interactive components need client-side rendering, why don't you just create a client component for the div where you're using isUserTab?

Just wanna figure out  whether it can be achieved using ssr

if that's what you're looking for, you might want to create a function and wrap all the logic in there, then you assign it to isUserTab by calling it, i found some interesting server code that might help you

You can use getServerSideProps and pass that information to your component as props.
Basic implementation
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';
import Link from 'next/link';

const Layout = ({ isUserTab }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <Link href="/user/details">
          <a style={{ backgroundColor: isUserTab ? 'green' : 'transparent' }}>
            User
          </a>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/company/details">
          <a style={{ backgroundColor: !isUserTab ? 'green' : 'transparent' }}>
            Company
          </a>
        </Link>
      </nav>
      {/* Content goes here */}
    </div>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const pathname = context.resolvedUrl;
  const isUserTab = pathname.includes('/user/details');

  return {
    props: {
      isUserTab,
    },
  };
};

export default Layout;


Edit for app router
I couldn't find any information in the official documentation on how to get the pathname directly on the server side.
Below I used the usePathname hook. Just make sure to include "use client" at the top of your file to enable client-side rendering.
"use client";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

const Layout = () => {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const isUserTab = pathname.includes("/user/details");
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <nav>
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: isUserTab ? "green" : "transparent" }}>
            User
          </div>
          <div
            style={{ backgroundColor: !isUserTab ? "green" : "transparent" }}
          >
            Company
          </div>
        </nav>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};

export default Layout;


bear in mind that getServerSideProps only works in nextjs pages router, it is not supported in app router.

AAh I'm using App Router

@SriramPrasanth please check the updated answer

@HairyHandKerchief23 Thanks for the update but I know how to do it in ssr but appreciate help

If you’ve found a solution, please consider writing an answer and accept it so others can benefit from it

sorry misspelled there csr (Client Side Rendering)  but I know how to do it in ssr(csr) but appreciate help

Happy to help! If this answer works for you, feel free to accept it!
